# What is the difference between consumption smoothing and risk smoothing?

Tags: consumption, risk

So there is a body of literature that talks about consumption smoothing (e.g. Rosenzweig & Stark 1989) and another body of literature that talks about risk smoothing in the context of insurance.

What exactly is the difference and how are these two concepts related? In an insurance context, why is the literature more likely to talk about risk smoothing than consumption smoothing?